# Split 1 Column of CSV Into 3 Lists/Columns

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a CSV file with one column with the following data type of 500 emails:

```
[['Lindsey Jessica <xyz@icloud.com>'], 
['Jonathan Bob <a@xyz.edu>'],
['Homer Simpson <b@xyz.edu>']
```

I need it to be put in a new CSV file with 3 columns separated by

```
**FirstName** **LastName** **Email**
```

I managed to separate the one column of the CSV into a list of 3 elements each:

```
["['Lindsey", 'M', "<lindsey@icloud.com>']", "['Jonathan", 'Andre', "<andre@xyz.edu>']", "['Greg", 'Kohl', "<kohls@gmail.com>']",...etc]
```

But now I need it to write to a CSV to look like this:

```
      Col 1    Col 2   Col 3
Row 1 John     Doe     <mail-noreply@google.com>
Row 2 Joe      Doe     <mail-noreply@google.com>
Row 3 Jacob    Doe     <mail-noreply@google.com>
```

And preferably get rid of those "< >" signs on the emails so I can import them into mailchimp. I can't figure out how to write my list into 3 columns however..

My code:

```
import csv

filename = ('email_list1.csv')

with open(filename, 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    email_list = list(reader)
    email_list = (' '.join(str(v) for v in email_list)) ## Convert to string
    email_list = email_list.split() #Split into seperate elements in a list: first, last, email

## Trying to print out in columns instead of rows
out = open('email_list2.csv', 'w')
for element in email_list:
    out.write(element)
    #print (element)
    out.write('\n')
out.close()
```

I tried using the zip function to no avail so I'm not sure if the best way is to separate into three lists like

```
firstname = []
lastname = []
email = []
```

or to just write them to 3 columns. Thanks

Comment: what does the input actually look like in your csv, is it comma delimited? Don't you already have three columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

a=[['Lindsey Jessica <xyz@icloud.com>'], 
['Jonathan Bob <a@xyz.edu>'],
['Homer Simpson <b@xyz.edu>']]


mylist=[elem[0].split() for elem in a ]

"""Output[['Lindsey', 'Jessica', '<xyz@icloud.com>'], ['Jonathan', 'Bob', '<a@xyz.edu>'], ['Homer', 'Simpson', '<b@xyz.edu>']]"""

mylist1=[]
#removing '<' and'>' and creating a new list name mylist1
for elem in mylist:
    elem[2] = elem[2][1:len(elem[2])-1]
    mylist1.append(elem)
#writing to a csv file 
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    myf = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    myf.writerows(mylist1)
```

Comment: First, it gives me an error `elem[2] = elem[2][1:len(elem[2])-1]
IndexError: list index out of range`. If you remove that line however, it writes correctly to the CSV as long as you make it write to 'w' instead of 'wb'. Also, in the CSV it prints blank lines after every real line. EDIT: I realized not everyone has a last name written so elem[2] sometimes will not work, probably need an IF statement?

Comment: for the given samples the above thing worked fine...make some tweaks to meet your requirement. You can add an if loop to check the last name

Comment: Is there a way to check if elem[2] actually exists in the for loop? Like if it holds a value or is empty like .empty() in C++?

Comment: if elem[2]: valuates to true if it is non empty

Answer (score 0):

Your original csv file is delimited by whitespace, you can set the `delimiter=" "` and then write the row to another csv file remove the `<>` with str.strip:

```
import csv
with open("in.csv", 'rt') as f,  open('out.csv', 'wb') as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    for row in r:
        row[2] = row[2].strip("<>")
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Output:

```
Lindsey,Jessica,xyz@icloud.com
Jonathan,Bob,a@xyz.edu
Homer,Simpson,b@xyz.edu
```

Answer (score -1):

use `csv.writer`

```
...
writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
...
  writer.writerow(element)
```

you can also use `element[2].strip(['<', '>'])` to get rid of the <>

Comment: Doing this, out = open('email_list2.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
for element in email_list:
    writer.writerow(element)
out.close()
Results in this: http://i.imgur.com/MYrCWA5.png

Comment: Oh okay, your list split into three elements is something else entirely